# Python Requests Exception Safety

Tags: exception, python-requests

A day with spotty internet has revealed numerous bugs in my python application. I'm using *requests* to get information from a webservice. I've already written code that checks if the return status is 200 or else but I didn't check for connection problems.

Here is my question:

*Should I wrap **every** GET/PUT/POST call in a try/except block?*

My goal is that the user have a nice experience and not have to restart the program.

Bonus points for showing me a lightweight way to wrap all my existing calls.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is always good to implement exception handling. It does not only help to avoid unexpected exit of script but can also help to log errors and info notification. When using Python requests I prefer to catch exceptions like this:

```
try:
    res = requests.get(adress,timeout=30)
except requests.ConnectionError as e:
    print("OOPS!! Connection Error. Make sure you are connected to Internet. Technical Details given below.\n")
    print(str(e))            
except requests.Timeout as e:
    print("OOPS!! Timeout Error")
    print(str(e))
except requests.RequestException as e:
    print("OOPS!! General Error")
    print(str(e))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Someone closed the program")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should:

```
try:
    r = requests.get(http://www.example.com)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print(r.url, " Status Code: ", r.status_code)

except requests.ConnectionError:
    print(r.url, " Failed to connect")
```